# AngularJs toggling function for selected item in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of items, and I have enable/disable method as an option for each item in a list.

I want to toggle only one item in a list:
[image]

Current implementation toggles all items in a list, and changes class icons for all.

HTML

```
<div class="device" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'open': item.isOpen}">
  <!-- Enable/Disable-->
  <a href="#" class="m-r-20" ng-click="test.toggleMethod(item.Id)"> 
    <span class="{{test.buttonClassIcon}}" title="{{test.title}}"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Controller

```
model.enabled = true;
model.toggleMethod = function (deviceId) {

    if (model.enabled) {
        locationService.start(deviceId).then(deviceList);
    } else {
        locationService.stop(deviceId).then(deviceList);
    }

    model.enabled = !model.enabled;
    model.buttonClassIcon = model.enabled ? 'fa fa-bell' : 'fa fa-bell-slash';
    model.title = model.enabled ? 'Enable' : 'Disable';

};
```

When I click bell, it changes class to all, and toggles global variable.

Comment: I dont see any definition of `toggleMethod()` in your controller ? is it `toggleAlarmMethod()` ?

Comment: Moreover, what isOpen doing ? not defined too in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an `enabled` property for each element in the list.

```
model.items.map(function(item){ 
   item.enabled = false; //  or other default value
});
```

and the in the html :

```
<a href="#" class="m-r-20" ng-click="test.toggleMethod(item)"> 
    <span ng-if="item.enabled" class="fa fa-bell" title="Enable"></span>
    <span ng-if="!item.enabled" class="fa fa-bell-slash" title="Disable"></span>
</a>
```

or you can use `ng-class` or create functions like `getTitle(item.enabled)` which returns the corresponding title.

and the `toggleMethod`:

```
model.toggleMethod = function (device) {
    var deviceId = device.Id;
    if (device.enabled) {
        locationService.start(deviceId).then(deviceList);
    } else {
        locationService.stop(deviceId).then(deviceList);
    }

    device.enabled = !device.enabled;
};
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/7f63jpa5/).

Hope this is what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function you dont enable/disable the selected item , instead you enable/disable a model object.
I am going to make an assumption , according to your snippet.

Since you have the item id or you can pass the $index(the position into the items  array) you could do :

```
//also pass $index into ng-click function
      <a href="#" class="m-r-20" ng-click="test.toggleMethod(item.Id,$index)"> <span class="{{test.buttonClassIcon}}" title="{{test.title}}"></span> </a>
```

**and into function body check the selected item:**

```
  model.toggleAlarmMethod = function (deviceId,indx) {

        if ($scope.items[indx].enabled) {
            locationService.start(deviceId).then(deviceList);
        } else {
            locationService.stop(deviceId).then(deviceList);
        }

//enable/disable selected item
        $scope.items[indx].enabled = !$scope.items[indx].enabled;
        $scope.items[indx].buttonClassIcon = $scope.items[indx].enabled ? 'fa fa-bell' : 'fa fa-bell-slash';
        $scope.items[indx].title = $scope.items[indx].enabled ? 'Enable' : 'Disable';

    };
```